# jmeter - How I can iterate a json response to get all the keys and related value

Tags: java, jmeter, jsonslurper

there is a way to get all keys and related values of a json?
I don't know the fields in output, then I can't use json extractor.
I've found this code, but it returns only the keys:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def traverse
traverse = { tree, keys = [], prefix = '' ->
    switch (tree) {
        case Map:
            tree.each { k, v -> 
                def name = prefix ? "${prefix}.${k}" : k
                keys << name   
                traverse(v, keys, name)
            }
            return keys
        case Collection:
            tree.eachWithIndex { e, i -> traverse(e, keys, "${prefix}[$i]") }
            return keys
        default :
            return keys
    }
}

def content = new JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

traverse(content).each { println it }
```

Output:

```
....
devices[24].creationDate
devices[24].updateDate
devices[24].attributes
devices[24].attributes.name
devices[24].attributes.location
devices[24].attributes.address
devices[24].attributes.latitude
devices[24].attributes.longitude
devices[24].attributes.brand
devices[25].deviceId
devices[25].deviceStatus
devices[25].deviceType
devices[25].creationDate
devices[25].updateDate
devices[25].attributes
....
```

could you help me to retrive keys and values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear how does your JSON look like and what form of the output do you expect.

It might either be as simple as:

```
content.keySet().each {println it}
```

or you might want to amend your code to include attribute value if it's not a [JSON Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp), something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def traverse
traverse = { tree, keys = [], prefix = '' ->
    switch (tree) {
        case Map:
            tree.each { k, v ->
                def name = prefix ? "${prefix}.${k}" : k
                if (!(v instanceof Map)) {
                    keys << ["$name": v]
                } else {
                    keys << name
                }
                traverse(v, keys, name)
            }
            return keys
        case Collection:
            tree.eachWithIndex { e, i -> traverse(e, keys, "${prefix}[$i]") }
            return keys
        default:
            return keys
    }
}

def content = new JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

traverse(content).each { println it }
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. How can I separately print the name and value after that?

Comment: Do you have update?